# Angular 2 ngrx/store calling an Observable service call on the result of another Observable service call

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to learn and understand Rxjs and ngrx/store

I have two api calls, the first one gets me an array of character names, the second one gets me the inventory of a character.

How do I run the second function through the array returned by the first one, using ngrx/store action/reducers/effects?

This are the service functions:

```
public getCharacterNames(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this._http.get(this._url + '/characters?access_token=' + this._key)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
}

public getCharactersInventory(characterName: string): Observable<Bag[]> {
  return this._http.get(this._url + '/characters/' + encodeURI(characterName) + '/inventory?access_token=' + this._key)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => {return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'); });
}
```

These are the actions:

```
public loadCharacters(): Action {
  return {
    type: Gw2Actions.LOAD_CHARACTERS
  };
}

public loadCharactersSuccess(characters: Character[]) {
  return {
    type: Gw2Actions.LOAD_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
    payload: characters
  };
}
```

This is the reducer:

```
  case Gw2Actions.LOAD_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS: {
    return action.payload;
  }
```

And this is the effect I tried using:

```
@Effect() private loadCharacters$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
  .ofType(Gw2Actions.LOAD_CHARACTERS)
  .map((action) => action.payload)
  .switchMap(() => this._gw2Service.getCharacterNames())
  .map((characterNames) => {
      let characters = [];
      characterNames.forEach((characterName) => {
        let characterBags = this._gw2Service.getCharactersInventory(characterName)
          .subscribe((res) => res);
        characters.push({
          name: characterName,
          bags: characterBags
        });
      });
      return characters;
    }
  )
  .map((characters: Character[]) => this._gw2Actions.loadCharactersSuccess(characters));
```

Comment: `.map((characterNames)` part seems wrong to me, but not able to figure out what needs be done there :|

Answer (score 0):

I suggest separating the two challenges of Rxjs and ngstore. This following is an approach to resolving inventories from character names. Hopefully you'll be able to map it into your ngstore effect.

```js
let charNames$ = Rx.Observable.of([{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]); //mock names
let getInventoryFromName = name => Rx.Observable.of({owner: name}).delay(1000); //mock inventory

let result$ = charNames$.switchMap(names => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(names.map(n => getInventoryFromName(n.name))));

result$.subscribe(res => console.log('got some inventory/user pairs: ', res));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried implementing something like that and I couldn't get it to work.. I guess I'm missing or misunderstanding something